# Retry failed MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

**Background**

I have an PayPal IPN handler in PHP`(5.2) that processes transactions and store date in a MySQL database. The site has low activity.

Occasionally the MySQL query fails. (Very rarely) I log everything and if a PayPal message failed to be processed I can just look in my log file and resend the PayPal message.

**Ideas / Concerns**

But I was wondering if I could make the process a bit more robust and instead have the handler re-try the mysql query before giving up.

I probably want to wait a little bit - not hammering multiple query attempts immediately after each other.

I was hoping to find some patterns for this - searching for stuff like "php mysql query retry" without having much success in that.

**Questions**

1. Are there good practice guides for this?
2. Existing libraries?
3. Is a simple loop and `sleep` between each query attempt ok, or can that have undesired side-effects? Too native?

Comment: why not to just check on error after query and retry if true? another way just to mark this query as "undone" and then cron job will make run through all "undoned" and re-execute them every few minutes.

Comment: So you're saying retry immediately after the failed query?

Comment: As for cron jobs - I'd then create a way to resume the processing of the remaining transaction. It's not just one single query - but multiple sets and some reply on the data from the previous.

Comment: so why not? mostly query fail when table(row) locked. try-after-fail is recommendation from MySQL documentation. (dont remember where exactly, but i'm pretty sure, that i read it).

Comment: and you can combine that practices. after 10 retries - pass it to cron for example.

Comment: p.s. "create a way to resume" - you have initial path, or post params, or single function for that logic with many updations... so it'll be easy to do it. Another way - make stored procedure on MySQL side for hard logic.

Comment: Ok - so retry a few times after the query then fall back to a cron log with cached POST data. That makes sense. So no need for any timed delay between queries? (I knowledge of MySQL isn't that good that I know what good practices are here.)

Comment: When you have a problem, read about it first. But seems like you're trying to solve it without understanding why that happens. I highly recomend to read about [InnoDB lock model](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html). Here you can find answer. P.S. But first.. just make shure you know **why** you have fails on insert (99% it's "lock" failure) and after google for resolving lock problem.

Comment: What is the cause of the fail - fix that cause then won't need to worry.

Comment: Problem is that I don't have full control over server. I don't host it myself. I'd contacted support and they said "that's just what happens some times...". Which is why I then began to look at ways to deal with it. Probably shouldn't have listened to them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good transaction safe code in the php world is not the norm but there are plenty of examples if you look in java or .net code samples.

Most good database code I've seen puts queries in a function and retries about 3 times immediately before giving up and logging/queuing.  Hopefully that will take care of your problem.

Best practice would be to use innodb tables and put all your critical sql statements in a transaction that is either committed or rolled back. That way your data is in a consistent state even if one particular query fails. (note this can also compound locking problems if you are not careful).

You don't want to do a long sleep with polling as this could hang your users browser. They need an immediate response to confirm that the purchase went through.  Putting the job in a queue with a cron job or server daemon is another way to go, but doesn't give the user the immediate feedback and is probably overkill for this purpose.

If immediate retries don't work you've got some other kind of underlying locking problem, reason for failure that you need to workout.

Comment: Right, that's interesting. I wasn't sure if it was good practice to implement retries. In this particular case I'm dealing with messages from PayPal and not a human end user. I'll try to implement a retry system as well as looking closer into what might cause my queries to fail form time to time. I don't host the hardware myself and therefore don't have full control of the environment. Which is why I want to make the code a bit more robust if I can.